# How to find a string and select it to the end (unknown) in php

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos

I need to find and select all the youtube links in a text with php in order to replace them with the proper embed code, but i don't seem to find the way.

**1- Where the link start:**
The link's start might change between `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video_id>` and `https://youtu.be/<video_id>`  and i think `strpos()` would do that job, the problem is....

**2- Where it ends:**
The link might have (or not) a query string attached what makes its length unknow, so the only way is select between  `https://www.youtube.co....` or `https://youtu.b...` and the next white space which would be the end of the link.

I need to replace the link with the proper youtube embed code.

Any idea how to select the link?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This looks like a simple task for a regular expression

Comment: i tried `strpos` with `substr` but i think it's not enough. I don't know regular expressions, is there a way or tool that i can use to get a pattern that suits my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
(https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*?)(?:\s|$)|(https:\/\/youtu\.be\/.*?)(?:\s|$)
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/LzvgPa/2)

Usage:

```
$re = '/(https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*?)(?:\s|$)|(https:\/\/youtu\.be\/.*?)(?:\s|$)/';
$str = 'abc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx5qFachd3A def https://youtu.be/Dx5qFachd3A ghi';
$embedStart = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="';
$embedEnd = '" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$str = preg_replace($re,$embedStart.'$0'.$embedEnd,$str);

echo $str;
```

you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) to replace it with your embed code.

Comment: Hi @Zuyas thanks a lot for your answer. Being the string `dsighksd siofh sdoifvh sdoivh sdipov sdiopvhj sdviphjsd viopj sdpiovj sdpvioj sdviphsiǘghjsd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx5qFachd3A ivpjsdfpvihjsdf pvijsdfvp wjfbaw ñhqwfu ghwqe fuigh wefuiagh https://youtu.be/Dx5qFachd3A fuio cfhiouacfh weoauicfh` The output is: `[
     [
       "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx5qFachd3A ",
       "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx5qFachd3A",
     ],
     [
       "https://youtu.be/Dx5qFachd3A ",
       "",
       "https://youtu.be/Dx5qFachd3A",
     ],
   ]
`

Comment: is it possible to achieve `[match1, match2]`

Comment: try my new usage example, does this work for you? if yes, please mark as answer